# Get returned items from function inside setTimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

So I need a little delay in my JavaScript for a function inside a loop that should get called every 500 ms:

```js
function myFunc(num) {
    return num++;
}

var theNum = 0;

while (theNum != 10) {
    theNum = setTimeout(myFunc(theNum), 500);
}
console.log("All done");
```

However, `All done` never gets logged.

Comment: Your theNum value will be always 0. So you will be in infinite loop. You are thinking that it will get changed in `myFunc` but it's wrong..you Should have some logic inside while loop itself to increment theNum variable value.

Comment: @navanth How can I make it change it then?

Comment: Even if this wasn't an infinite loop "All done" would be logged first in all cases.

Comment: @Andy it doesn't get logged for me. Try running the exact code yourself in the browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're calling the function immediately. You need to pass the function *reference* to the `setTimeout` instead.
2. And you're also creating an infinite loop due to that issue.
3. Even if you corrected this problem "All done" would still be logged first before any of the timeouts completed.

So you need to rethink the approach. Put the timeout in a function and if `theNum` is less that 10 call the function again with the incremented number ([`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) allows you to pass in arguments after the delay). Log "All done" when the count reaches 10.

```js
function myFunc(num) {
  return `Number: ${num}`;
}

function loop(theNum = 0) {
  if (theNum < 10) {
    console.log(myFunc(theNum));
    setTimeout(loop, 500, ++theNum);
  } else {
    console.log("All done");
  }
}

loop();
```